# How To Put A Constraint On Relationships In A Domain Class, In Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

I have a domain three domain class like this :

**Tasks.groovy**

```
class Tasks {
    static belongsTo = [ user : User ]
        //other fields
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
}
```

**User.groovy**

```
class User {
    //relationships. . . .
    static belongsTo = [ company : Company, role : Role, resource : Resource]
    static hasMany = [ holidays : Holiday, tasks : Tasks]
    //other fields
    }
```

**Holiday.groovy**

```
class Holiday {
    static belongsTo = User
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    //other fields
}
```

Now when I create a `Tasks` instance, I want to put a constraint such that the `Tasks` `startDate` and `endDate` doesn't fall within the `User`'s `Holiday`s `startDate` and `endDate`. And throw and error if it has.

I want a way to put this constraint on my domain class itself(i.e on `Tasks`).

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a custom validator.

```
startDate(validator: {val, obj->
    obj.user.holidays.every{holiday-> val <= holiday.startDate || val >= holiday.endDate }
})
```

You can encapsulate your custom validation logic as a closure. You will have to add similar logic for endDate as well.

Comment: Nice! It would probably be better to encapsulate some of that logic into the User class, so the code becomes more clear and respects the Law of Demeter. Something like `startDate(validator: { startDate, self -> self.user.canStartTaskAt(startDate) })` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with having a `createTask` function in the User domain, since Task should not be fiddling with variables that are so far removed (self -> User -> Holiday -> startDate).

It is quite clear that the User knows when its holiday starts and ends and thus would easily validate the given start and end dates for a new Task.